# Loading X resources from .Xresources and .Xdefaults for Emacs

Tags: emacs, x-resources

Emacs, as far as I remember, must load the `.Xresources` file on startup and read the font rendering settings from there. But mine does this only if I run `xrdb merge` first and then start emacs. I think I have something misconfigured here.

As my emacs starts as a systemd service I've just added `ExecStartPre=xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` in the emacs.service. It practically solves the issue. But I still want to know why it's not working as it shouldbe?

Also, my .Xdefaults is a symlink to .Xresources and I use KDE on openSUSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working exactly the way it should. `~/.Xresources` is conventionally loaded when you log in. Many distributions do this as part of the X session startup scripts. If you don't use a full destkop environment, you may need to add it to your login scripts, which would be systemd in your case, just like you did. The resources from `~/.Xresources` are loaded into the X server and apply to all programs that display on that X server.

You may be confusing `.Xresources` with `~/.Xdefaults`, which is loaded by each X client application when it starts, and then applies to this application. When using X remotely, the `~/.Xresources` file is on the X server side, whereas the `~/.Xdefaults` file is on the client side.

Note that Emacs only loads `~/.Xdefaults` if no resources are loaded in the server (more precisely, if `XResourceManagerString` returns `NULL`). It also loads `~/.Xdefaults-$HOSTNAME` unconditionally. I don't know why.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've updated my question, can you comment on that?

Comment: @contemplator Emacs doesn't load `.Xdefaults` if some resources are loaded in the server. I don't know why.

Comment: How can I check that (are some resources loaded)? It is indeed works with `~/.Xdefaults-$HOSTNAME`, nice workaround.

Comment: @contemplator Run `xrdb -query`. I think if it produces no output, Emacs reads `.Xdefaults`. I'm not completely sure because I don't know when `XResourceManagerString` might return an empty string rather than NULL.

Comment: There is a rather long list of settings in the output. I think most of them are default opensuse ones. My settings mixed in there, but one option, for which I care most, [differs](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b51a313eb0e4517a9028#file-gistfile1-txt-L344) from [my config](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b51a313eb0e4517a9028#file-gistfile1-txt-L407). Is it possible to know where it came from?

Comment: @contemplator You'd need to trace your login files. Note that most environments load `~/.Xresources` when the X session starts. Having both `.Xdefaults` and `.Xresources` is redundant in most cases (it can only be useful if you use X11 remotely on hosts that don't have your dot files).

Comment: it turned out that the KDE sets these Xft.* settings on startup according to its preferences. My settings in `.Xresources` and `.Xdefaults` were completely ignored or overwritten by it.

Comment: "When using X remotely, the ~/.Xresources file is on the X server side, whereas the ~/.Xdefaults file is on the client side."  This one sentence both succinctly describes and solves soooo many of my issues, THANK YOU.  I have read SO many posts that just say ".Xresources is the new/modern/non-deprecated .Xdefaults." But I am pretty much *always* accessing a remote system using a local X server and remote X clients through SSH tunneling, so of course trying to "switch" caused issues.  Even in 2022 this answer is useful!!!